# RTP Multiplexing or Mixing?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, rtp

I'm designing a real-time voice comm system that I want to use RTP with. Here's my general requirements:

- Every user streams one audio stream to the server
- The incoming stream may be compressed differently, depending on the source (a SIP trunk, an Android phone, a desktop client, etc.)
- Users can pick which streams they want to receive

If the users had unlimited bandwidth and there wasn't a limited number of ports, I would just have them each open an RTP stream with the server for each stream they wanted to receive. However, a lot of the users will be over a 3G or 2G network, so my question is, how can I bundle the streams (chosen by the user) into a single RTP stream?

One option I've seen is multiplexing the streams into a single packet, but as far as I can tell, that actually goes against the RFC (however, there are working drafts for multiplexing).

Another option would be just mixing the audio together into one packet. Is that the recommended way to do this? I would have to normalize all of the chosen streams into one format first.

I'm very new to the whole VoIP/streaming media thing, so this may be a poor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to use tcp in order to not lose data.
you need to use rtp over tcp [see rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4571)

this allow sending several rtp stream over a single socket with a unique id per stream.

Comment: Is RTP over TCP a requirement for allowing RTP to traverse NATs as well?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you are having firewall issues maybe you will want to check HTTP Tunneling.

Comment: Why care about losing a few packets in an audio streaming application like VoIP? Especially for real time uses, you prefer RTP over UDP/UDP Lite than TCP. See http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/faq.html#tcp

Comment: losing of packets is very bad for audio / video syncing.
you need to identify the lost packets and add "silent" audio packets instead.